# Merge 2 Rows into one in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to merge 2 rows in Oracle DB but am facing problems doing it.

I have the following data set:

[image: table].

I basically want to get the sum of resource utilizations for both the materials in a single row.

I tried the group by function, but as expected it gives the sum of the 2 materials in 2 separate rows. Something like,

[image: this]

Is there any way to get those values in a single row? Something like

[image: this]

Comment: You can do this with a pivot, but keep in mind that this approach will get out of hand very quickly should you have many materials.  Do you always expect only two materials?

Comment: @Parfait Sorry, yes. Modified the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, there will be multiple materials. However not more than 10. If a material does not exist for a particular month, then the sum will be 0. I tried pivot and could get the month and sum for the materials in a single row. However, I could not get the material names in the same row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have written the following Pivot query:

WITH 
T 
AS 
(
   select pt.MONTH, pt.MATERIAL, pt.RESOURCE_UTILIZATION from RESOURCEUTILIZATION pt
     where pt.UNIT = 'K5832' and pt.MONTH = '201705'
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
   T
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(RESOURCE_UTILIZATION)
   FOR 
      (MATERIAL) 
   IN 
      ('CF_FILTER_15833-1','CF_FILTER-1')
)

However, it only displays the month and sum of resource utilizations for the particular month in a single row. Any idea how to modify it so that material names also appear in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are confident that you will only have two materials then you can achieve the same using a subquery.

```
select month,Material,sum(material) as 'Sum Resource Utilization', 'CF_FILTER_15833-1', (select sum(material) from TABLENAME where Material='CF_FILTER_15833-1') as 'Sum Resource Utilization' from TABLENAME where material='CF_FILTER-1';
```

Hope this helps.